# How to add SCSS to a component of an angular library

Tags: html, css, angular

I've created a library in angular 6. The problem is that styling is not applied. Here is my code:

**mycustom.component.html**

```
<div class="cutom-div">
    Hello
</div>
```

**mycustom.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "lib-mycustom",
  templateUrl: "./mycustom.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./mycustom.component.scss"],
})
export class MycustomComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**mycustom.component.scss**

```
.custom-div {
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
}
```

This was supposed to be simple. But there's no styling applied. I inspected the element also:

[image]

[image]

What else I'm missing out here. Please point out my mistake.

I'm building the library normally:

`ng build my-library` and then `cd dist\my-library>npm pack`

Comment: Can you try with `[className]`/`[ngClass]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#None

`None` means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This mode is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

```
@Component({
  selector: "lib-mycustom",
  templateUrl: "./mycustom.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./mycustom.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, // <- This need use for global style
})
```

Comment: let me try quickly

Comment: But i'm still confused why my code didnt work without that. I've seen many youtube videos and none of them used `encapsulation`

Comment: without that, `.custom-div` will be change with other identifier

Comment: without that, the scss cannot apply to other component 's template